# Quantidade mínima de bits necessária para representar números decimais

Tags: matemática, arquitetura-computadores, bits

Estou fazendo uma lista de arquitetura de computadores e um dos primeiros exercícios é bem básico:

> Qual a quantidade mínima de bits necessária para representar em binário cada um dos números decimais sem sinal abaixo?
>
> a)4095
> b)65534
> c)42319

Pensei em transformar os números em binário (dividindo por dois várias vezes) para ver sua representação em binário e assim achar a resposta, porém acredito que haja uma outra forma de responder isso sem precisar converter, mas não me lembro do professor ter ensinado isso em aula.

Existe realmente alguma outra forma? Não preciso da resposta do exercício, só a forma de resolver mesmo.

Comment: O que chama de decimais? Aí tem 3 inteiros. Está falando apenas de representação decimal?

Comment: @bigown Acho que "decimais" é pra ser "base 10".

Comment: É basicamente o que você disse. Você pode usar um logaritmo de base 2 se quiser simplificar – `2^n = 4095 :: n = log2(4095)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vou te ensinar e não resolver, como pediu.

Como você acha a quantidade de dígitos necessários para guardar um número decimal?

Na representação numérica decimal temos obviamente 10 dígitos diferentes. Então esta é nossa base.

A quantidade de dígitos necessários é o expoente. Então se você tem um número 7 precisa do primeiro número que seja potência de 10. Portanto 10 elevado a 1 já dá 10, e 7 cabe em 10. Então 1 dígito é suficiente para representar esse número.

Para facilitar e não ficar ana adivinhação eu posso ir fazendo a divisão por 10 até chegar em um número menor que 1. Quantidade de divisões feitas que você fez é a quantidade de dígitos necessários.

Se tiver o número 56, precisa de 10 elevado a 2 para dar 100 que caberia o 56. Então precisa de dois dígitos.

383 cabe em 1000, portanto 10 elevando a 3, então precisa de 3 dígitos e assim vai.

Quantos dígitos diferentes tem na representação binária? 2, certo? Então esta será a base. Para descobrir quantos dígitos binários (bits) são necessários precisa testar o primeiro expoente que faz caber o número que deseja.

Vamos dizer que tivesse o número 200. Você fazendo 2 elevado a 8 dá 256, então precisa de 8 bits.

Como eu descubro isto facilmente? Eu vou dividindo o número por 2 sucessivamente até chegar em um número **menor** que 1. Então 200 precisa de 8 divisões (resultaria em 0,78125 que não nos interessa).

Vamos dizer que o número é 256. Se fizer 8 divisões o resultado dá 1. Mas só deve parar quando der menos que 1. Então precisa fazer mais uma divisão. De fato o número 256 precisa de 9 bits para ser representado binariamente.

Se isso é difícil de entender, entenda pelo decimal. Quantos decimais podem ser representados com apenas um dígito? 10, óbvio, né? Mas o 10 pode ser representado por um dígito? Claro que não, precisa de 2. Por que? Porque começa do 0. então o décimo número é o 9. Acontece o mesmo com binário.

Se o número fosse 256 precisaria de 9 bits, já que 8 bits pode representar 256 números, de 0 até 255.

Basicamente é isso, agora é só fazer as contas para estes casos do exercício.

Se tiver uma calculadora com essa capacidade pode usar logaritmo com base 2. Mas tem uma pegadinha que se der um número exato, tem que adicionar 1 bit. Como o número começa em 0, se o número dá exatamente a potência calculada precisa adicionar um dígito. Outra forma é adicionar 1 ao número que deseja calcular e só depois aplicar o logaritmo. Assim não precisa fazer uma exceção.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 13):

Para calcular o número de bits, você pode usar Log<sub>2</sub>(X), arredondado para cima:

- Log<sub>2</sub>(4095): 11.9996477365, ou seja, `12`;
- Log<sub>2</sub>(65534): 15.9999559718, ou seja, `16`;
- Log<sub>2</sub>(42319): 15.3690179165, ou seja, `16`.

Comment: Também utilizo essa fórmula.