# Utilização "bytes" e "bits"

Tags: c, c++, terminologia, byte, bit

Qual a utilidade *bytes* e *bits*?

Eu estou lendo uns livros de programação C e C++ que falam sobre bytes e queria saber qual é a utilização ou pra que serve estes termos.

Por exemplo, nesta tabela abaixo fala sobre bytes:

> ```
> Tipo  Descrição                            Tamanho             Intervalo
> char  caractere                           1 bytes -128     a 127 ou 0 a 255
> Int       inteiro                             2 ou 4 bytes    -32768 a 32767 ou -214783648 a 214783647
> float Ponto flutuante                     4 bytes         -1.7E38 a 1.7E38 (precisão de 6 dígitos)
> double    Ponto flutuante com 2x de precisão  8 bytes         -1.7E38 a 1.7E38 (precisão de 16 dígitos)
> void  vazio   0 bytes
> ```

Comment: "Utilidade"? Depende. Só é útil se você precisar do computador ou de dados armazenados, senão não serve pra nada. (falando em informática). Agora, se quer saber "o que é", a pergunta muda um pouco.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um bit (*BInary digiT*) é a menor unidade que podemos encontrar na abstração da computação. Os computadores trabalham com pulsos (todos de uso real desde o final da segunda guerra mundial são elétricos) com um indicativo de estado ligado ou desligado. Nos computadores modernos isso se dá por uma voltagem maior ou menor. A lógica do computador é binária, por isso ele é rápido e preciso. Ao contrário do [decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47854/101) que usamos (baseados nos nossos dedos) o binário só tem dois estados, falso ou verdadeiro e tudo é composto através disso.

Então temos a base 2, e representamos todos os dígitos possíveis com 0 e 1. O próximo número seria 2 no decimal, no binário será o 10, porque para representar um terceiro número só com um dígito extra. Aí o próximo será 11, e depois virá 100, que é o mesmo que 4 em decimal.

Quando você tem [8 dígitos diferentes você tem um byte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200308/101) (em todas arquiteturas atuais é assim, mas poderiam ter escolhido outro tamanho). Foi definido assim porque é um número redondo (programador trabalha pensando em binário e números redondos são 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc.) que atende bem as necessidades dos principais números. Um dos motivos é que ele pode ser usado para mapear os caracteres que precisamos usar, a tal da tabela [ASCII](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156951/101), que tem 128 caracteres diferentes. Isto daria 7 dígitos para representar tudo (2 elevado a 7 dá 128), arredondaram para 8.

Há a nomenclatura de *nibble* para 4 bits, mas não existe dado real só com essa quantidade de bits, ele é usado porque alguns coisas podem ser representadas só com eles, o que pode até haver alguma compactação e manter dois valores no mesmo byte (BinarY TErm), assim como podemos manter 8 valores booleanos diferentes em 1 byte. No passado já teve arquiteturas com 4 ou 8 bits em cada byte.

Daí tudo o que fazemos é composto por bytes, inclusive alguns tipos de dados já são compostos por uma quantidade específica de bytes, por exemplo um inteiro tem 4 bytes (tipicamente), ou um caractere estendido em formato UTF-16 tem 2 bytes, ou uma data costuma ter 8 bytes, ou um pixel pode ter 1, 2, 3 ou 4 bytes (os dois últimos os mais comuns hoje me dia) e assim por diante. Em um inteiro de 4 bytes temos 32 bits, portanto é 2 elevado a 32, ou pouco mais de 4 bilhões, que é a quantidade máxima de números diferentes que isso pode ser representado neste tipo.

Um tipo de ponto flutuante tem um cálculo mais complexo, mas ele tem 32 ou 64 bits e é possível representar cerca de 4 bilhões ou 16 quintilhões de números diferentes, embora pareça que é mais pela forma como ele calcula isto, ele chega mais longe mas pula muito número.

Os processadores são capazes de lidar melhor com certos tipos de dados com esses formatos e quantidade bytes.

O tamanho mínimo que podemos armazenar, lidar ou transportar é 1 byte. Na prática dependendo do que for fazer pode ser no mínimo uma [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214972/101), ou até algo maior. Tem caso que o mínimo é 4KB. Então um tipo que só precise de 1 bit (porque ele é [booleano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214972/101)) ocupará 1 byte, no mínimo.

Uma curiosidade é que escrever KB está errado. KB seriam 1000 bytes. Mas como precisamos de números redondos em binário um quilo de bytes para nós são 1024 bytes, e aí deve ser representado corretamente por KiB. Claro, todo mundo entende que KB é 1024 e não 1000. Só que aí a pessoa compra um HDD e ele vem medido em KB de verdade e a pessoa acha que o fabricante está roubando ele.

Outra curiosidade: 1 KiB são 1024 bytes, 1 KB são 1000 bytes e 1 Kb são 1000 bits, e claro, 1Kib são 1024 bits. As pessoas intercambiam isso erradamente.

O assunto é simples mas dá um capítulo de um livro se for falar de tudo, imagino que só queria um resumo. E o site está cheio de informação extra, como já mostrei em alguns *links*.

Bytes são usados para medir o espaço ocupado por algum dado, e ele sempre será um conjunto de 8 bits (estados de verdadeiro ou falso). É um termo abstrato que foi criado para dar entendimento à unidade mínima de valor que lidamos de fato no computador.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ficarei agradecido se alguém me informar o que tem de errado na resposta, achei que essas coisas eram de conhecimento universal.

Comment: +1 Obrigado, ôtimo isso sim é reposta rápida e explicativa!